# converting tif to jpg using imagemagick

Tags: vb.net

Iam trying to convert Tiff to jpg file, its converting fine using imagemagick but content is missing when converting to jpg

Note: i have added annotation in tiff image as Stamping. But Couldn't convert it properly.

```
    Dim sourcefile, loadfile, sCmdArgs1  As String
    sourcefile = "S:\wip\ppa\opoint\OPP20110526\test.jpg"
    loadfile = "S:\wip\ppa\opoint\OPP20110526\test3.tif"
    sCmdArgs1 = """" & loadfile & """" & " """ & sourcefile & """"
    sCmdArgs1 = "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.6.1-Q16\convert.exe " &  sCmdArgs1
    Shell(sCmdArgs1, AppWinStyle.Hide, True) '' calling convert.exe
```

I have attached link for my input image and output image.

Input:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_nzYHWVJJ7KaEVxT0RJZ1lGWlk/view?usp=sharing

output: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_nzYHWVJJ7Kem5FSkxsSTVIME0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: for me in- and output look the same O.o

Comment: If I run `compare test3.jpg test3.tif diff.jpg` using ImageMagick, they are almost identical apart from some speckles of noise here and there.